# Highcharts showLoading displaced

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, highcharts, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I call the showLoading method of a chart the show loading screen appears but on the wrong position. I am not sure which is causing this. I have created a plunk (http://plnkr.co/edit/FdBqoPJZmopNc4s33Jcg) but I could not reproduce the wrong behaviour with the plunk.

```
$scope.renderColumnChart = function (date) {
    var chart = {};
    $.each(Highcharts.charts, function (index, c) {
        if (c && c.renderTo.id === "column-chart")
            chart = c;
    });
    $scope.columnChartConfig.series = [];

    $scope.columnChartConfig.title.text = moment(date).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
    $scope.columnChartUrl = SharedService.createUrl(SharedService.createUrlDataByPeriod($scope.dimension, SharedService.getPeriodFromDate($scope.dimension, date), date, 0, 0, 1, [19]));

    chart.showLoading(); //TODO show loading wrong place
    $q.all([
        ColumnChartService2.getData($scope.columnChartUrl, globalConfig.oDataServer + globalConfig.ageGroups)
    ]).then(function (result) {
        $scope.columnChartConfig.series.push({
            name: "Personen pro Altersgruppe",
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            data: result[0].data
        });
        //chart.hideLoading();
    });
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

regards

### Additional Information

Here is the full code of the angular controller and the html template.

Controller

```
ManagementReporting.controller("CustomerHeadCountController", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$q', 'globalConfig', 'SharedService', 'MultiLineChartService', 'ColumnChartService2',
function ($rootScope, $scope, $q, globalConfig, SharedService, MultiLineChartService, ColumnChartService2) {
SharedService.cleanUpCharts();
$scope.title = 'Customer Head Count';

var init = function () {
    $scope.dimension = SharedService.getGranularity()[0];
    var ranges = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    $scope.before = ranges[3];
    $scope.after = ranges[5];
    $scope.referenceDate = new Date(moment().subtract("month", 0).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    $scope.period = SharedService.getPeriods($scope.dimension, $scope.referenceDate).period;
};
init();

// TODO add charts

$scope.refresh = function () {
    $scope.processCharts();
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////  EVENTS  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// when route change!!!!
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('change.activeSite', 'Anzahl Kunden auf basis verrechneter Einsätze (jeder Kunde in der Dimension einmalig gezählt)');
    $scope.processCharts();
});

$scope.processCharts = function () {
    $("#modal-processing-report-data").modal("show");
    $scope.lineChartConfig = MultiLineChartService.getConfig();
    $scope.lineChartConfig.series = [];

    $scope.url = SharedService.createUrl(SharedService.createUrlDataByPeriod($scope.dimension, $scope.period.value, $scope.date, $scope.before, $scope.after, 1, [17]));
    $scope.urlRegression = SharedService.createUrl(SharedService.createUrlDataByPeriod($scope.dimension, $scope.period.value, $scope.date, $scope.before, $scope.after, 1, [21]));


    $scope.columnChartConfig = ColumnChartService2.getConfig();
    $scope.columnChartConfig.series = [];

    $q.all([
        MultiLineChartService.getData($scope.url),
        MultiLineChartService.getRegressionData($scope.urlRegression)
    ]).then(function(result) {
        $scope.lineChartConfig.series = result[0].data;
        $scope.lineChartConfig.series.push(result[1].data);
        $scope.renderColumnChart($scope.date);

        var normal = Enumerable.from(result[0].data).where(function(record) {
            return record.name === "Normal";
        }).toArray()[0];

        $scope.average = parseFloat(normal.avg.toFixed(2));
        $scope.minimum = normal.min;
        $scope.maximum = normal.max;
        $("#modal-processing-report-data").modal("hide");
    });
}

$scope.$on('multilinechart.click', function (angularEvent, highchartEvent, point) {
    var date = new Date(highchartEvent.point.x);
    $scope.renderColumnChart(date);
});

$scope.renderColumnChart = function (date) {
    var chart = {};
    $.each(Highcharts.charts, function (index, c) {
        if (c && c.renderTo.id === "column-chart")
            chart = c;
    });
    $scope.columnChartConfig.series = [];

    $scope.columnChartConfig.title.text = moment(date).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
    $scope.columnChartUrl = SharedService.createUrl(SharedService.createUrlDataByPeriod($scope.dimension, SharedService.getPeriodFromDate($scope.dimension, date), date, 0, 0, 1, [19]));

    //chart.showLoading(); //TODO show loading wrong place
    $q.all([
        ColumnChartService2.getData($scope.columnChartUrl, globalConfig.oDataServer + globalConfig.ageGroups)
    ]).then(function (result) {
        $scope.columnChartConfig.series.push({
            name: "Personen pro Altersgruppe",
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            data: result[0].data
        });
        //chart.hideLoading();
    });
}
}]);
```

HTML Template

```
<div>
<!--
    <div class="row">
        <div data-ng-include="selectionHeader.url"></div>
    </div>
-->

<div class="dateselector"
     data-dimension="dimension"
     data-before="before"
     data-date="date"
     data-period="period"
     data-after="after"
     data-refresh="refresh()">
</div>

<div class="well">
    <highchart id="line-chart"
               data-config="lineChartConfig"
               data-chart="lineChart" />
    <div class="text-center">
        <span translate>Minimum: </span> {{minimum}}, <span translate>Maximum: </span> {{maximum}}, <span translate>Durchschnitt: </span> {{average}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="well">
    <highchart id="column-chart"
               data-config="columnChartConfig"
               data-chart="columnChart" />
</div>

<!-- Modal Section -->

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-processing-report-data" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-processing-report-data-label" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-processing-report-data-label">Processing...</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can't reproduce the wrong behavior, how can we know what is the source of the problem? Anyways, here's an example of the loading options: http://jsfiddle.net/b95xb1qj/ Try working with them and let us know if the problem persists. And please find a way to show the problem for us to test our solutions.

Comment: I have extended my question with the code of the controller and the html template

Comment: I didn't mean to just put your code here. I could have seen the code in plunker. What I meant was for you to make the plunker produce the error you are mentioning, or use another site like jsfiddle.net for coding, and let us see the actual error and to be able to fix it from there.